# Are all shower arms removable?

Tags: bathroom, shower, bathroom-fixtures

[image]I was wondering if all shower arms are removable because I am unable to figure out how to remove one?

Comment: What country? We need a picture.

Comment: I have updated. But I'm curious to know if every shower arm type is removable. Especially, for the United States.

Comment: no, not all shower arms are removable ... the answer cannot possibly be `yes` ... please think about what you are asking

Comment: Removable, probably.  Easy is another question and am sure some are a pain in the neck(or other parts) to remove.

Comment: I doubt this is a theoretical question about "all" shower arms, so how about a picture of _your_ shower arm. That will help determine if _yours_ is removable, since that's probably what your question _really_ is about.

Comment: Show us a pic of your actual shower arm, preferably with the escutcheon (round cover plate with the hole in it) removed so that we can see into the hole behind it.

Comment: @jsotola it must be yes. Everything is removable with enough force and the right type of saw. Reassemble-able after however...

Comment: @Grant +1 ... lol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Every** and **all** are unforgiving words. I personally have never seen a shower arm in the US that wasn't removable. Typically they unscrew. Regardless of the type of supply line (usually copper) the fitting at the outlet is threaded to take a threaded shower arm. There may be some instances where shower arms are soldered onto the supply line but I've never seen it and I think it's against code in the US. If I'm wrong, I'm sure one of the experts here will correct me.

Comment: Note that it may have been installed very tightly by a gorilla or may have corroded over time and is not somewhat locked into place.  Use caution trying to extract it because it can break or you can tear the elbow mounted to the wall off.